# Winline probability from a deck of cards

Tags: probability

$52$ cards are fairly shuffled, and $15$ are laid out as in the example below:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\color{red}{6\heartsuit}&\color{red}{8\diamondsuit}&{4\spadesuit}&\color{red}{2\heartsuit}&\color{red}{3\heartsuit}\\
\hline
{6\clubsuit}&\color{red}{8\heartsuit}&\color{red}{X\heartsuit}&{2\spadesuit}&{Q\spadesuit}\\
\hline
\color{red}{J\diamondsuit}&{J\clubsuit}&{7\clubsuit}&\color{red}{9\diamondsuit}&\color{red}{A\diamondsuit}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

A *winline* consists of a path from left to right where you can start with any of the $3$ cards in the left column and must move into the next column by either number or suit - the path does not have to be vertically adjacent, so $Jd, 8d$ is allowed.

The above example has only $6h,8h,Xh,2h,3h$. If, for example, $9d$ was $7s$ then $Jd, Jc, 7c, 7s, Qs$ would be another.

We can see $Xh$ in the center column is the only feasible candidate to hit in this case.

What is the probability a dealing has at least $1$ winline?

Comment: That's a cool table +1

Answer (score 1):

First, solve for a single 5-card deal. Based on your problem, I defined two cards that share either a rank or suit as "neighbors". Qs and Qd are neighbors, and Qd and 8d are neighbors, but Qs and 8d are not neighbors.

I visualized the deck of cards laid out as a grid, organized by rank and suit. All cards along a single column have the same suit, and all cards along a single row have the same rank (Ace, 5, 10, Queen, etc.). Therefore, all cards directly above, below, left, or right of a card are all neighbors.

A winline is then defined as any path through a sequence of five cards that has only vertical and/or horizontal moves.

Consider the following table. Assume that the numbers 1-5 represent distinct card ranks, and the letters A-E represent card suits. The actual ranks/suits don't matter; this is only to indicate which ranks and suits are matched up to create a winline.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
{1A}&
{1B}&
{1C}&
{1D}&
{1E}\\
\hline
{2A}&
{2B}&
{2C}&
{2D}&\\
\hline
{3A}&
{3B}&
{3C}\\
\hline
{4A}&
{4B}\\
\hline
{5A}\\
\hline
\end{array}

The first card in the winline is always 1A. This represents any rank and any suit. From there, the second card in the winline is either 1B (same rank, different suit) or 2A (same suit, different rank). The third card in the winline can be either 1C, 2B, or 3A... and so on. Basically now the winline problem consists of solving for every path through this table starting at 1A, moving one space at a time, and never visiting the same space twice (i.e. 1A-1B-2B-2A-1A is not a legal path).

The reason for this level of abstraction is that each subsequent card in the winline affects the probability of the next card being a "neighbor". There are 24 legal paths under these constraints, and the sum of the probabilities for each yields the probability of a winline for a single group of 5 cards.

$1A-1B-1C-1D-1E
$

P(all five cards share the same rank) = P(five of a kind) = $0$

$1A-2A-2B-2C-2D\\
1A-1B-2B-2C-2D\\
1A-1B-1C-2C-2D\\
1A-1B-1C-1D-2D
$

P(adjacent cards match rank three times and one time matches suit) = $4 * {72 \over 5997600}$

$1A-2A-3A-3B-3C\\
1A-2A-2B-3B-3C\\
1A-2A-2B-2C-3C\\
1A-1B-2B-3B-3C\\
1A-1B-2B-2C-3C\\
1A-1B-1C-2C-3C
$

P(adjacent cards match suit twice and rank twice) = $6 * {792 \over 5997600}$

$1A-2A-3A-4A-4B\\
1A-2A-3A-3B-4B\\
1A-2A-2B-3B-4B\\
1A-1B-2B-3B-4B
$

P(adjacent cards match suit three times and rank once) = $4 * {3960 \over 5997600}$

$1A-2A-3A-4A-5A
$

P(all cards match suit) = P(flush) = $1 * {11880 \over 5997600}$

$1A-1B-2B-2A-3A\\
1A-1B-2B-3B-3A\\
1A-2A-2B-3B-3A
$

P(adjacent cards match suit twice and rank twice AND the first and last cards match suit) = $3 * {1188 \over 5997600}$

$1A-1B-2B-2C-1C\\
1A-2A-2B-1B-1C\\
1A-2A-2B-2C-1C
$

P(adjacent cards match suit twice and rank twice AND the first and last cards match rank) = $3 * {864 \over 5997600}$

$1A-2A-3A-3B-2B
$

P(adjacent cards match suit, suit, rank, suit, and cards 2 & 5 match rank) = ${4356 \over 5997600}$

$1A-1B-1C-2C-2B
$

P(adjacent cards match rank, rank, suit, rank, and cards 2 & 5 match suit) = ${144 \over 5997600}$

Let X = P(winline from five random cards) = P(all scenarios listed above) = ${43416 \over 5997600}$

Back to the original problem, you have specified that a winline can run through any combination of cards, one per column. This allows 3^5 or 243 potential winlines.

The probability that at least one of those is a winner is:
$1 - (1-X)^{243} \approx 0.82889$